# Error 13 Type-Mismatch in Assigning Sheet Variable in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, userform

```
Dim AN As Workbook
Set AN = Sheets("ANData")
```

Okay so the second line is the line that gets highlighted when I try to run the GUI. It worked last week but now I am getting a error 13 type mismatch. I am trying to have it reference the spreadsheet named "ANData".

Comment: `Dim AN As Worksheet`

Comment: I'm quite sure It didn't work last week either ^^, at least not exactly as it.

Comment: `On Error Resume Next` and `Err.Clear` ...Voila Err fixed!!

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments `Sheet` is a variable and `WorkBook` is another variable:

```
Public Sub TestMe()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim wb As Workbook

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Sheets("ANData")

    MsgBox ws.Name & " is in " & wb.Name

End Sub
```

Comment: I tried this and it gave me runtime error -2147418113(8000ffff). It said it was a automation error and catastrophic failure
Dim AN As Worksheet
Dim wb As Workbook
    
Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set AN = wb.Sheets("ANData")

Comment: I did try it and it didnt pop up a message box, my GUI opened though

Comment: @R3DSTON3R - Can you restart the PC, open a new Excel, name one of the steets "ANData" and try again?

Comment: I can give it a shot

Comment: So I had to change Dim ws As Sheet to Dim ws As Worksheet but it did post the message\

Comment: @Vityata shouldn't it say `Worksheet` rather than `Sheet` ?

Comment: Well I dont know how but my excel spreadsheet added a secondary woorkbook and I couldnt delete it. So I moved the entire database over to a new spreadsheet along with the GUI and now it works. I think the program was confused about having two workbooks

Comment: @Rawrplus - then it is a good idea to change it here as well - `Set ws = wb.Sheets("ANData")`